# Python, creating a program that reads numbers from file and calculates the sum

Tags: python

my file contains only of numbers:

```
22 33 56 2 1.4 67.4
34.5 49 11.2
```

I want to create a program with python code that reads a file with numbers (doesn't have to be this one) and then calculates the sum of those numbers.

does anyone know how to proceed with this one?

okej so after your help I tried to make my own version based on what I´ve learnt in class so far:

```
my_file = open("mesurements.txt", "r")

sum1 = 0

for line in my_file.readlines():

    line = line.strip("\n").split()

    for i in line:

        sum1 += float(i)

print(sum1)
```

do u think something like this is correct (it works for me but there could be some mistakes maby?)

Comment: A lot of people here know this. But first, try it yourself. If you encounter any specific error/problem where you are stuck, you can come back.

Comment: You should first open the file in read mode and then read the numbers line by line or all at once. While reading, you could strip the lines of unnecessary spaces and split them if more than one number is given in a line. Afterwards, it should be an easy job to get the sum of it. Try it yourself!

Comment: Your version now works just fine, good job. If any of the answers helped you to achieve this, mark it as accepted. For more information on how to accept an answer see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your working answer:

```
values = [float(x) for x in open('demo.txt').read().split()]
print sum(float(i) for i in values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Say the file `numbers.txt` contains your numbers:

```
22 33 56 2 1.4 67.4
34.5 49 11.2
```

Try the following to calculate the sum of all numbers in the file:

```
def sum_file(file):
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        return sum([sum([float(x) for x in line.strip().split(' ')]) for line in f])

#print the result
print("{0:.2f}".format(sum_file("numbers.txt")))
```

Test for 6x6 matrix:

```
9.54 3.62 9.13 9.24 6.94 1.61
2.32 1.72 8.06 8.89 9.21 6.06
4.46 3.42 8.44 4.83 9.90 1.84
2.38 6.83 7.04 9.66 1.53 8.92
3.06 9.02 8.69 7.18 9.18 1.29
1.55 7.57 9.20 3.90 3.84 2.56
```

`sum_file("numbers.txt")` results in `212.63`.